# get twitter user details by using Oauth.js

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, cordova-plugins

T have tried following code

```
OAuth.initialize(public-key);
            OAuth.popup('twitter', function(error, result) {
                console.log(result);
                result.get('/account/verify_credentials').done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                });       
                result.get('me').done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    alert('Hello ' + data.name)
                })
            });
```

I am able to login using that popup but not getting the info.
I am getting oauth_token and oauth_secret_token only.
I am getting following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://oauth.io/request/twitter/me. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can you please suggest me to get the user info.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I got it. I have used following code and its working.

```
result.get("/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json").done(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```